# Iterate through custom array in ember js

Tags: templates, ember.js

I need to iterate through custom Array directly in the ember template like:

```
{{#each [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] as |num|}}
  <div class="input-group-{{num}}">
    .
    .
    .
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

How can I do it? The above code doesn't render anything.

Comment: You can't do that.define property in particular context and use it in hbs

Comment: @kumkanillam I know I can set it to a variable in component and use, but, I feel that won't be the correct way of coding.

Comment: @GaneshK what makes you think that wouldn't be correct?

Comment: I am sure, That's the right approach.

Comment: @mikej Just defining an array in component, I feel it'll look ugly and purposeless for a new programmer viewing the code.

Comment: If you give it a meaningful name that describes what the list is then it should help make things clearer to a new programmer than a list of numbers in the template. Maybe an example that is closer to your actual code would help too?

Comment: @mikej okay thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this, just use a helper. You can either create an helper or use an existing one.

For example, by using [ember-array-helper](https://github.com/kellyselden/ember-array-helper) you can express it like that:

```
{{#each (array 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10) as |num|}}
    {{num}}<br>
{{/each}}
```

Or, use [range helper](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#range) of ember-composable-helpers. Such as:

```
{{#each (range 10 20) as |number|}}
  {{! `number` will go from 10 to 19}}
{{/each}}
```